# Yii framework error while installing composer asset plugin

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to install the yii framework. I already had a composer installed.
so i run the command to install composer assset plugin:

```
php composer.phar global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.1.1"
```

the command runs for sometimes and gives an error:

> Fatal error:Call to undefined method
>   composer\package\Loader\ArrayLoader::praseLinks<>

but, new project is created with:

```
php composer.phar create-project yiisoft/yii2-app-basic basic 2.0.8
```

Comment: Try to update composer with `composer self-update`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
php composer.phar update
```

or else

```
php composer.phar self-update
```

Answer (score 0):

Composer version is old. You will need to update composer.
Run the following command -

```
php composer.phar self-update
```

This should resolve the error